# disable on device the android device disable Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Tags: android

If you search for "Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0" you will see a couple of question and answers.

My need is different:
I am using real device, not emulator, never will.
**Not in logcat** I want to filter the message, but disable it at device OS somehow.

My device is has rooted Android 4.2.1. I can't upgrade it to 4.3 atm, because THL didn't released it ( phone is a THL w8s )

As I know for rooted devices there is a few app, which can disable some logging.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723#c47)

> **The issue isn't in the SDK/ADT tools**, so the last maintenance release
>   we made has unfortunately no impact on this bug.
>
> As stated above, **the issue is in the system-image that runs in the
>   emulator and/or the phones**. We'll have a fixed system-image for the
>   emulator at some point, I do not know when exactly.